# ArcGIS Server REST API Query - Where date strings are greater than

Tags: arcgis-server, rest

I am working with an ArcGIS Sever 10.41 rest service that contains many scientific records. These records have a date field called sample_date but it's stored as a string. See below.

sample_date ( type: esriFieldTypeString , alias: sample_date , length: 8000 )

I've been trying to query the last year's records to no avail. Since this field is stored as a string I was trying to just get those records which contained the string 2018 but that did not work and returned empty records. See below.

/arcgis/rest/services/folder/MapServer/2/query?where=sample_date+LIKE+'*2018*'&outFields=*&f=JSON"

Any suggestions for a better approach to querying all records from the last 12 months even though the field is stored as a string?

Comment: Does 10.41 server support SQL queries? CAST("FIELDNAME" as DATE)

Comment: This question is misleading in the use of "date"  to refer to a string field. If it's a string field, all you need to do is use the `like` operator correctly, which would involve URL-encoding the wildcard character.